# How to upload an array of images to firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Rightnow i'm using a array.map method to upload each file and gets the url in response but the thing is it gives me "C:\fakepath\pic1" in some files which creates a messs although it uploads it correctly(means i've seen the images in my firebase storage) but not get back the url in response
This is the code i'm using to put files

```
uploadPicsArr.map(function (pic, index) {
                var storageRef = fbStorage.ref('images/'+token+'/'+pic.name);
                // Upload file to Firebase Storage
                var uploadTask = storageRef.put(pic.file);
                uploadTask.on('state_changed', null, null, function () {
                    var downloadUrl = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
                    userInfo[pic.name] = downloadUrl;
                })
                if (uploadPicsArr.length == index + 1) {
                   fbDatabase.ref('users').push(userInfo).then(function (success){
                        browserHistory.push('/home');
                    });
                }
            })
```

`fbStorage`: firebase.storage()
`uploadPicsArr` = an array of objects and every object has a property name and file
`name`: name of the selected file
`file`: selected file
Please tell me what i'm doing wrong or if there's any other better way to upload the whole array and get each file URL in response then it would be better

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to pass the snapshot as a parameter in the complete function:

```
uploadPicsArr.map(function (pic, index) {
    var storageRef = fbStorage.ref('images/'+token+'/'+pic.name);
    // Upload file to Firebase Storage
    var uploadTask = storageRef.put(pic.file);
    uploadTask.on('state_changed', null, null, function (snapshot) {
        userInfo[pic.name] = snapshot.downloadURL;
    })
    if (uploadPicsArr.length == index + 1) {
       fbDatabase.ref('users').push(userInfo).then(function (success){
            browserHistory.push('/home');
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: No it was a promise issue like i had to wait for storage to resolve which i wasn't [react app](https://github.com/mkamranhamid/react-Firebase-Playlist/blob/master/app/components/Signup.js#L40)